# JointsWP / Foundation 6 top menu FOUC

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

Since adopting JointsWP with Foundation 6 I'm having a real problem with FOUC on the Topbar. I must have built about 10 sites using JointsWP and Foundation 5 and never had an issue, but the 2 F6 sites I'm working on seem to have a couple of seconds of totally unstyled topbar before load.

Anyone else experience this? Any tips??

Comment: This was an issue with an older version of Foundation 6, however, it has since been fixed. Which version are you running?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - I updated the Foundation core and it fixed the issue. Well, it improved it anyway!